# Windows server response time very high

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, iis

Server Specs

```
Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit
Provider : Fasthosts
.Net Framework: 4.0
 6 GB RAM (its using 4.6 GB)
```

i have a website with thousands of pages structured like

```
folderone/1/one to 500.aspx
folderone/2/one to 500.aspx
.
.
folderone/500/one to 500.aspx
```

To load this pages for the first time after the release, for each folder it takes about 20 to 30 minutes and once one page is loaded the rest of the pages loads fine. This happens for all folders.

And this repeats every time i restart the server, when a added anything to app_code or if i change the web.config.

My site is mainly works Google and due to this problem its giving errors. Any help will be highly appreciated please. i am happy to buy a beer for you if its resolved.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you add memory to this server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to precompile your site when you build it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863(v=vs.100).aspx

**Web Deployment Overview for Visual Studio and ASP.NET**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698.aspx#basic_deployment_tasks

Precompile the project.

By default, web site projects are not precompiled, and .aspx and .ascx pages are not precompiled in web application projects. In some large applications, the process of compiling can result in a slight delay that might be noticeable the first time a web page is requested after deployment. For information about web project compile and merge options and how to specify them, see How to: [Deploy a Web Project Using One-Click Publish in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337.aspx).

Comment: i have the site hosted on the server, is it possible to run this on windows server itself on the original site path, if so is it the right command iam using C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -p "D:\Plesk\VHOSTS\domain.co.uk\httpdocs\translators\".... it seems not working. Please help this is first time i am usign this tool. sorry to be pain

Comment: No it needs to be done before it hits the IIS folder where the site exists.  I added some information to the answer.

Comment: i found somewhere on mSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227430(v=vs.85).aspx  , we can use inplace prcompilation which suits my case. so do you think i am ok to run the precompilation on actual domain folder itself?

Comment: Many thanks greg. It works finally. i used aspnet_compiler -p D:\Plesk\VHOSTS\domain.co.uk\httpdocs -v / ............... it keeps the source files as they are and compiled the pages. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Well, simple - first request Triggers compile of the Website including all pages.

Game over. Thousands of files in one compile run. Dead.

ASP.NET is not made for this type of Approach. Dont put physical files there. Use a CMS like Approach.